# Are the TTS and speech recognition list questions welcome?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I think that these two questions could be interesting and useful lists:

- [Name current software/online services for HIGH-QUALITY speech recognition in German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1881/name-current-software-online-services-for-high-quality-speech-recognition-in-germ)
- [Name current software/online services for HIGH-QUALITY text-to-speech (TTS) in German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1880/name-current-software-online-services-for-high-quality-text-to-speech-tts-in-ge)

The criteria are fairly well-defined ("high-quality speech recognition" and "high-quality TTS"). At least, they could be edited to good questions. I don't find them very different from other lists like "[German learning apps for Google Android](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1471/german-learning-apps-for-google-android)" and "[Classic childrens books that are unknown outside of DE/A/CH ?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/669/classic-childrens-books-that-are-unknown-outside-of-de-a-ch)"

Should they be re-opened?

Comment: [Q&A is hard, let’s go shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: I think a question of whether they exist for German is on-topic but asking for recommendations between them is a shopping question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As questioner i still like to hear an answer and thought esp. on SE with all the developers someone actually can give some insight what software offers high-quality algorithms. I see @RegDwight point he linked towards and afaik he mainly closed it because no one gave an answer, but i miss a bit the sure instinct, esp. as most have upvoted the speech recognition question and then it gets closed by a single mod. Why not at least make it a community wiki then?

On most sites you start a bad subjective answer trend (Apple or Mac), agreed, but thats really not the danger here and i asked more for what software has the highest quality, its not really the same as apple or mac. You will find enough not closed highly upvoted questions on SE concerning *what editor is the best (auto-complete, debugging...) for a special programming language, this is objectively answerable. We have maybe a dozen questions here concerning software translation services & co. So i dont see how this can ruin the quality.

Imho reopen them as cw when the site has more users and will probably get some answers. I believe the question would yield some pretty good answers concerning quality of algorithms on EL&U, but im not inclined to ask the same there, as RegDwight is mod there :) and im interested in German speech recognition.